# SQLAlchemy - How to map ManyToMany using autoloaded association tables

Tags: many-to-many, sqlalchemy

I am autoloading an MSSQL db.  There are a few ManyToMany assoc tables.  I'm not sure how to map each side.  Here's a typical example of how they look in the db:

```
Table: tbUsersToGroups
PK: ID_UserToGroup
FK: User_ID
FK: Group_ID
```

So I can successfully autoload that assoc table and the Users and Groups tables per below, but everything I've tried to map the sides has failed.

```
class UserToGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbUsersToGroups'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'extend_existing':True,'schema':'dbo'}
```

and

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbUsers'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'schema':'dbo'}
```

and

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbGoups'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'schema':'dbo'}
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have mapped the association table to a class.  It's very unusual and probably going to cause you some pain to combine an association object with a many-to-many relationship.  If the association table doesn't have any other columns of interest, you can drop the mapping 
and use a many-to-many relationship:

Edit: I missed the fact that you're doing per-table reflection, rather than full database reflection;  For a many-to-many, you have to tell sqlalchemy about the table, but without mapping it to a class:

```
user_to_groups_table = sqlalchemy.Table('tbUsersToGroups', Base.metadata,
                   autoload=True,
                   extend_existing=True
                   schema='dbo')

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbUsers'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'schema':'dbo'}

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbGoups'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'schema':'dbo'}
    users = relationship(User, secondary=user_to_groups_table, backref="groups")
```

If there *are* columns in the association table that you want to have an object-oriented access to, you should use two One-To-Many relationships to relate the three classes;  Optionally, you can also use an association proxy to get a convenient many-to-many property for when you only need to use those extra columns occasionally (and they have defaults):

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy
class UserToGroup(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbUsersToGroups'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'extend_existing':True,'schema':'dbo'}

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbUsers'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'schema':'dbo'}
    usergroups = relationship(UserToGroup, backref="user")
    groups = association_proxy("usergroups", "group")

class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tbGoups'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True,'schema':'dbo'}
    usergroups = relationship(UserToGroup, backref="group")
    users = association_proxy("usergroups", "user")
```

Comment: Thanks @TokenMacGuy.  When I try your first example, I get an InvalidRequestError saying (basically) that 'tbUsersToGroups' isn't defined.  So then I try to define an autoloaded class 'UserToGroup' but then I get an AttributeError 'UserToGroup' has no foreign_keys.  However I can see the foreign keys by doing `for f in UserToGroup().__table__.foreign_keys: f`.  Any clues?

Comment: I don't use `autoload` very often without full database reflection, so I missed the need for the table declaration;  Please see my edit.

Comment: The only reason I can't use full database reflection in this instance (unless you know a way around it) is that on 2 occasions, I have to override the column definition for MSSQL TIMESTAMP columns, which are server-generated, meaning SA can't insert.  Anyway, I'm giving your edited version a go now.  Thanks so much again

Comment: You can override anything you like; just supply a `Column` entry for the fields that are reflecting poorly, and sqlalchemy will use your definition in favor of the reflected one;  On the other hand, full database reflection can be slow; so you don't need to use it if it's not actually convenient for you.

Comment: Really?!  I think I'll take a look at full reflection because this is super painful.  I just need to migrate this MSSQL to MongoDB so my motivation manually defining the MSSQL side is very low.

Comment: Ok, so SA is still saying that 'user_to_groups_table' is undefined, even though it is declared BEFORE it's called.  I suspect that its to do with my structure moreso than your solution, so I'll mark this as an answer and try my luck with full reflection.